# Restoring previous version of application on Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I deployed a modified version of MusicApp on my Ubuntu Phone, however the application (when not connected to computer & Ubuntu SDK) does not run, it either crashes or starts and shuts down, don't know why. As a consequence I'd like to restore a previous (stock) version of Music App. Is there any way to do this? If not, is there an easy way of securing the already existing app to make it restorable after deplying modified version?

Comment: did you tap and hold on the app - that should give you the option of uninstalling, then just get the stock from the store

Comment: Thanks Mateo, however I thought there may be a system for managing versions of software using e.g. apt

Comment: apt isn't used for the apps, click packages are used to install apps